# Signature collision in Windows 11, why?

Tags: hard-drive, usb, backup, sata

I'm running into a problem in Windows 11 I can't figure out, maybe someone has ideas...

- I have a hard drive connected to my motherboard in a hot swap SATA rack called "Project 20". This is my work drive.
- I occasionally plug in a HDD to make a mirror backup with FreeFileSync in a USB SATA dock to a drive called "Project 20 BCK". It detects new files and copy those.

I usually plug USB drive with PC running, making the copy and eject. But this time i have plugged in the drive while OS was shut down. Booted with both drives connected and this is what happened:

- I see "Project 20" HDD but USB drive is blinking when accessing it and getting "location not available" message. So volume name is mixed up (it is the "Project 20 BCK" drive) and files inaccessible.
- Disk management showing the real "Project 20" as "Offline" with signature collision.

That is strange since drives should have different signatures. I have formatted them manually and individually. FreeFileSync copy the files, not cloning signatures!

- My backup drive "Project 20 BCK" got corrupted, and folders are a bit messed after repair.
- My work drive "Project 20" is fine.

Why does Windows mix up and corrupting my drive with a different name (altough same content) that has never been cloned (only simple copy), and is on a different port (external USB vs internal SATA). How can i avoid this?

Is it possible that windows 11 with "fast startup" enabled acts more like hibernation and mixing and corrupting the drive when booting with two drives with same folder and file structure?

Thanks for any ideas!

Windows repair shows this on corrupted drive: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4RrJ5.jpg

Comment: Do things go back to normal if you boot without the USB running and connect it later?

Comment: After this i shut down, and disconnected both drives. Booted up and connected drives one-by-one through USB dock. Work drive (Project 20) is intact, no errors. Backup drive (Project 20 BCK, but having a wrong label of "Project 20" is corrupted.

Comment: The problem might be in the dock, if both devices are connected to it in parallel.

Comment: Do you have a Linux disk of any kind? It would be useful to see what's shown by `fdisk -l` (fdisk can also write a new signature if needed).

Comment: No linux unfortunately. Windows repair shows this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4RrJ5.jpg

Comment: Can you refer to my above comment and give more details about the dock and how the disks/enclosures are connected?

Comment: @harrymc "Project 20" was in the PC case in a SATA rack similar to "Icy Box 168SK-B", and "Project 20 BCK" backup drive in an AXAGON ADSA-SN USB dock. "Project 20" had no issues after shutdown and removal of both drives and booting up and connecting individually (using the USB dock), but backup drive is corrupted.

Comment: Did you have problems with electrical surges or sudden power cuts?

Comment: @harrymc no power problems. I have a suspicion that it might have something to do with "fast startup" in Win11. It acts more like hibernation instead of shutdown. So I have added an external drive with the same exact content while the OS was "sleeping" (despite my intentions of a fresh boot) and booting up could have made it mix up things?

Comment: Was an offline repair performed on the drive, as that's filesystem corruption - execute: `ChkDsk <DriveLetter>: /OfflineScanAndFix`

Comment: @JW0914 thanks for the suggestion, yes chkdsk repair was performed, but it became messed up. I have since formatted and overwritten the corrupted backup drive with a new full backup. My goal is to avoid this to happen again. I have a suspicion it has something to do with "fast startup" see my previous comment.

Comment: @sp4rk There can be issues with Fast Starup when disconnecting drives that were connected with it enabled, as the filesystem on those drives is still mounted and in use at the time of hibernation _(this comes up frequently in dual-boot scenarios when users aren't aware they have to fully shutdown Windows prior to booting into BSD/Linux in order to access the drive)_, however AFAIK it should never create an issue if plugging a drive in while hibernated since it's the filesystem being mounted that creates the issue, not the detection of new peripheral hardware.

Comment: @JW0914 I had "data drive" mounted, than hibernate. Plug in "data mirror drive" too and wake computer. Somehow windows thinks "data drive" is connected twice (they have same data on them), and knocks it offline with "signature collision". In the same time it messes up "mirror drive" because its trying to use it as the "data drive" for some reason. It would imply that the OS registers drives by their file structure when hibernated and can mix it up with a copy. But that would be strange...

Comment: @sp4rk: The drive signature counts, not the file-structure. In addition, Fast Startup has no effect on hibernation, so that is not the problem. I would instead avoid (un)plugging drives during hibernation, since this conserves disk-info in memory and you have demonstrated that it can cause confusion. You should take care to dismount/eject before hibernation.

Comment: @harrymc Thank you for the answer! I was using shut down to avoid problems, but it seems "Fast Startup" does hibernate instead. Now i have disabled it to avoid future problems. At least i hope it will affect this behavior.

Comment: @sp4rk: Even if hibernation was a by-product of sleep, it's the same answer. Either eject before sleep/hibernation or do a cold shutdown without Fast Startup (this will also do the eject for you). In theory this shouldn't be happening, perhaps worth a Feedback Hub report to Microsoft.

Comment: @harrymc Thanks, I'm going to follow what you have suggested. This will hopefully avoid similar future problems.